# Qt C++ - access a dynamically created Widget (QLineEdit)

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm making an app where practically all UI elements are dynamically created... Among them is a list of `QLineEdit` + `QPushButton` pairs generated from a number the user inputs. Buttons open up a `Dialog` window to find files, `QLineEdits` is for data verification/editing, and all that has to end up in a database. Sometimes he only has to input 3 values, sometimes 10.

```
QLineEdit* warstwaEdit[iloscWarstw]; //iloscWarstw - number user inputs
QPushButton* warstwaDialog[iloscWarstw];
for(int i=0; i<iloscWarstw; i++) {
    warstwaEdit[i] = new QLineEdit;
    warstwaEdit[i]->setFixedHeight(25);
    warstwaEdit[i]->setFixedWidth(400);
    ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsFormularzWarstw->layout()->addWidget(warstwaEdit[i]);

    warstwaDialog[i] = new QPushButton;
    warstwaDialog[i]->setFixedWidth(100);
    warstwaDialog[i]->setFixedHeight(30);
    warstwaDialog[i]->setText("Dodaj element");
    ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsFormularzWarstw->layout()->addWidget(warstwaDialog[i]);
    mapperDialog->setMapping(warstwaDialog[i], i); 
    connect(warstwaDialog[i], SIGNAL(clicked()), mapperDialog, SLOT(map()));
}
```

But I can't get the Dialog to pass the String to "his" label. In Dialog's slot I'm trying to use the

```
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsFormularzWarstw->layout()->warstwaEdit[i]->setText(filepath);
```

But apparently `QLayout (`) (nor `scrollAreaWidgetContentsFormularzWarstw`) have a member "warstwaEdit". `qDebug()` used in that slot indicates that a proper `i` is being passed. TreeDump indicates that `ScrollAreaWidgetContentsFormularzWarstw` is the parent.

I'm kind of at a loss. I got a really weird app for my first encounter with Qt...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax you're using to access the widget doesn't seem correct.

Since you are storing your widgets in an array, you don't need to access them via the layout actually. Just access them directly on your array:

```
warstwaEdit[i]->setText(filepath);
```

An alternative would be to name your widgets:

```
warstwaEdit[i]->setObjectName("some name");
```

Then to access them with `find`:

```
QLineEdit* lineEdit = ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsFormularzWarstw->findChild<QLineEdit*>("some name");
lineEdit->setText(filePath);
```

Comment: Bingo! The alternative worked. I converted 'i' to String, added that to a String containing "warstwaEdit". 'i' is passed to dialog slot and converted to String there,, and I've used findChild<QLineEdit*>("warstwaEdit"+number). Thanks! I should be able to finish the app smoothly from this point on

Comment: don't use findChild, just store the pointers when you create the widgets!